# Implementing 2-factor authentication for Windows Server RDP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, security, remote-desktop

We want to implement 2-factor authentication for all our servers.

For SSH, we use authkeys. What can we use for Windows Server 2008 R2 RDP?

Comment: Off topic: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PhoneFactor](https://web.archive.org/web/20120206014517/http://www.phonefactor.com/solutions/terminal-services-authentication/) has a TS solution. It may fit the bill for you.